# what is this eye icon in Android Studio

Tags: android, privacy

[image: creepy little eye icon]

Whenever I start the program a little eye icon appears in the upper right corner above the scroll bar.  It can't be clicked.  I assume it's Google uploading my usage data.  How can I disable that?

[image: eye icon in android studio]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that icon just means IntelliJ (or Android Studio) is analyzing the file. AFAIK nothing related with usage data uploading.

After a short while it should turn green if everything is correct, yellow if you have warnings and red if you have errors.